# Importing mgcv fails because Rlapack.dll cannot be found

Tags: r, ironpython

I want to link to the R statistical package in IronPython by using the [R.NET](http://rdotnet.codeplex.com/) library. It's been working fine, but now I need to use R's [mgcv](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mgcv/index.html) library.

Importing `mgcv` fails (import is done with the command `rdn.r.EagerEvaluate("library(mgcv)")`, where `rdn` is an IronPython object that wraps the R.NET library). When the import fails, Windows opens a dialog box that says: "The program can't start because Rlapack.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem."

Of course, R never would have worked in the first place if Rlapack.dll was missing, so what is going on?

Comment: Don't worry about answering this; I have solved the problem and will post the solution in 8 hours, when SO's lockout expires.

Comment: I don't know where IronPython is looking for Rlapack.dll, but R is looking for it in its own home directory (.../R-2.x.x/bin/i386 or /R-2.x.x/bin/x64 for the 64bit version). That's not the directory of the R executable, nor of the library. Adding this one to your path might help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I inspected the dependencies of the `mgcv` package; they include the base package `Matrix`. As it turns out, `Matrix` has been compiled to a dll (found at ${R_HOME}/library/Matrix/libs/i386/Matrix.dll) by the R development team. That dll needs to link to Rlapack.dll, which for some reason it cannot find when R is called from R.NET in IronPython.

The solution was to drop a copy of Rlapack.dll (which you can find in ${R_HOME}/bin/i386/) into the same directory as Matrix.dll. Now every day is Sunday.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with `compositions.dll`.

So instead of copying the `Rlapack.dll` to the directory where `compositions.dll` exists, I added the `bin` directory to the `PATH`.

```
string rhome = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("R_HOME");
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(rhome))
    rhome = @"C:\Program Files\R\R-2.14.0";

System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("R_HOME", rhome);
System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH") + ";" + rhome + @"\bin\i386");
```

Comment: It's odd. Adding R bin to `PATH` doesn't worked for me in Windows XP. But it worked in Windows 7!