# Rlapack.dll is missing from your computer - c# and R

Tags: c#, r

When I run a c# application through Visual Studio 2010, where R is integrated, I get the error: `The program can't start because Rlapack.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.`
I tried reinstalling the program but it did not work.
I also tried putting it in the folder that has the Matrix in it but it did not work. This solution was suggested in [StackOverflow Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7960738/importing-mgcv-fails-because-rlapack-dll-cannot-be-found).

I am running 64-bit Windows 7! The application is 32-bit.
There are two dll's. One in a folder called i386, and another one in the folder x64.

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using RDotNet;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {



        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            string dlldir = @"D:\Program Files\R-2.15.0\bin\i386";

            bool r_located = false;


            while (r_located == false)
            {
                try
                {
                    REngine.SetDllDirectory(dlldir);
                    REngine.CreateInstance("RDotNet");
                    r_located = true;
                }

                catch
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(@"Unable to find R installation's \bin\i386 folder.
                    Press OK to attempt to locate it.");


                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding the `dlldir` to the `PATH`-environment-variable?

Comment: are you running 32 bit or 64 bit windows

Comment: Any chance that you're trying to run a 64-bit application, linking with a 32-bit DLL?

Comment: Not sure how the PATH-variable works. Should I be using a specific name? 
Also, how do I if the DLL is a 32-bit one?

Comment: I am guessing that you're trying to load a 32-bit DLL based only upon the path listed in your code.

Comment: That's right! I just updated the question.

Comment: Are you compiling for x86,x64 or Any Cpu ? Also is the 32 bit path actually D:\Program Files (x86)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I just did and it worked: I put the dll in the bin folder of my application.

Comment: the dll is already present in my bin.i386 folder. I have also set Path vairable to C://ProgramFiles/R/bin/i386. But getting the same error while working with Web application instead of windows Form,

Answer (score 9):

I realize this has been answered, but that was back in 2012.  For anyone still having this problem with R version 3.4.3 or later in 2018, especially while trying to follow [the simple example](https://rdotnet.codeplex.com/) from the r.net home page, below is what I did to fix it:

1. In your code, before the line `REngine engine = REngine.GetInstance();`, add this line `REngine.SetEnvironmentVariables(@"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.3\bin\x64", @"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.3");`.
2. right click project, go to build and uncheck "Prefer 32-bit".
3. copy `Rlapack.dll` from `C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.3\bin\i386`
4. paste in both `C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.3\library\stats\libs\i386` and `C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.3\library\Matrix\libs\i386`
5. copy `Rlapack.dll` from `C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.3\bin\x64`
6. paste in both `C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.3\library\stats\libs\x64` and `C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.3\library\Matrix\libs\x64`.

Such a pain, but that is what finally got it to work for me.

Comment: for Python rpy2. Just 3/4/5/6 is enough.. thank you so much

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. I was stumbling on error "unable to load shared object 'D:/Home/R/R-3.3.3/library/stats/libs/x64/stats.dll' and this was the fix

Answer (score 1):

Try setting path variable `before` caling the dll:

```
     var envPath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH");
     string s = null;
     if (Environment.Is64BitProcess)
         s = @"C:\Program Files\R\R-2.15.0\bin\x64";
     else
         s = @"C:\Program Files\R\R-2.15.0\bin\i386";
     Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", envPath + Path.PathSeparator + s);
```